# Clicking when part of window changes color

Tags: autohotkey

I am trying to make a program that will click in a certain spot once a certain spot in a desktop application changes color. It goes from white to green words. Or is there someway I can figure out what command the client sends to the program when they click a certain button and then loop that command until the button is available.

I know this sounds confusing and weird, but please tell me what programming language is best for either of these options. Also I would like to know how challenging it would be to program, and how to do it. Currently I am using auto hotkey. If I need to clarify something, let me know. Thanks in advance.

Comment: i think i may have found it, the auto hotkey ImageSearch command http://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/ImageSearch.htm

Answer (score 1):

See [PixelGetColor](http://l.autohotkey.net/docs/commands/PixelGetColor.htm) in the AutoHotkey documentation.  Keep in mind that the pixel must be visible, and that the X and Y are relative to active window, unless changed by [CoordMode](http://l.autohotkey.net/docs/commands/CoordMode.htm).

```
PixelGetColor, OutputVar, X, Y [, Alt|Slow|RGB]
```

You can then compare the color with the one you're looking for.  Keep in mind that the colors are in BGR format, so 0000FF is red.  If you have a color in RGB, either change it (112233 => 332211) or use the RGB parameter.